# Some C++20 ranges views not compatible with std::copy

Tags: c++, std-ranges

In the code below, as it stands, doesn't compile. But replace `std::views::take(2)` with `std::views::drop_while` and the code compile. I do understand that the `take_view` and `drop_while` view do different things, non the less, it shouldn't matter if I want to take some or drop some, I still should be able to copy those elems into the container.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //std::views::drop_while([](const int val){return val < 9;}) |

    vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,8,9};   
    std::ranges::take_view res = v | std::views::filter([](const int val){return val %2 == 0;}) | std::views::transform([](const int val){return val*3;}) 
    |  std::views::take(2);
    decltype(v) filtered;
    std::copy(res.begin(),res.end(),std::back_inserter(filtered));
    for (const auto val : filtered)
    {
        std::cout << "val: " << val << '\n';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Tried to look for explanation on the net.
EDIT:
Error:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:23:14: error: no matching
> function for call to ‘copy(std::counted_iterator > >, main():: >,
> main():: >::_Iterator >, std::ranges::take_view > >, main():: >,
> main():: > >::_Sentinel, std::back_insert_iterator > >)’    23 |
> std::copy(res.begin(),res.end(),std::back_inserter(filtered));
> |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file
> included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/char_traits.h:39,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/string:40,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/streambuf:41,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:35,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/iterator:66,
> from /usr/include/c++/11/ranges:43,
> from main.cpp:9: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:611:5: note: candidate:
> ‘template constexpr _OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI)’   611 |     copy(_II
> __first, _II __last, _OI __result)
> |     ^~~~ /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:611:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: main.cpp:23:14: note:
> deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_II’ (‘std::counted_iterator
>
> > > , main():: >, main():: >::_Iterator >’ and ‘std::ranges::take_view > >, main():: >, main():: > >::_Sentinel’)    23 |     std::copy(res.begin(),res.end(),std::back_inserter(filtered));
> > > |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file
> > > included from /usr/include/c++/11/iterator:66,
> > > from /usr/include/c++/11/ranges:43,
> > > from main.cpp:9: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:325:5: note: candidate:
> > > ‘template typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if::__value,
> > > std::ostreambuf_iterator<_CharT> >::__type
> > > std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>,
> > > std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::ostreambuf_iterator<_CharT>)’
> > > 325 |     copy(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,
> > > |     ^~~~ /usr/include/c++/11/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:325:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> > > main.cpp:23:14: note:   ‘std::counted_iterator > >, main():: >,
> > > main():: >::_Iterator >’ is not derived from
> > > ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>’    23 |
> > > std::copy(res.begin(),res.end(),std::back_inserter(filtered));
> > > |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Please include the compilation errors.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ranges::copy`? Mixing algorithms based on the C++17 iterator system with C++20 iterators is generally *not* an appropriate choice. This is *especially* true in your case because `res` is *not* a common range, which means that its `begin()` and `end()` return different types, which is also why `views::common` exists.

Comment: Why don't you #include <algorithm> ? Works for me if to include it.

Comment: Also, you can simply use `auto` type specifier for `res`. `filtered` can simply be created with `ranges::to`, leading to a shorter - yet more descriptive - code sequence.

Comment: @Quimby Edited with error

Comment: @ÖöTiib How would that help me?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thanks for the copy suggestion. I didn't see it in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

Comment: @DeborahC for me (GCC 13.1.0) it does define overload of std::copy that does what you request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range `res` doesn't model Common Range, i.e. its `begin()` and `end()` have different types.

The easy solution is to simply use the range version of the algorithm instead:

```
    std::ranges::copy(res, std::back_inserter(filtered));
```

If you really need start and end (for a function such as `std::accumulate()` which is not yet rangeified), then we'll need to convert to a common range.

```
    auto common_res = res | std::views::common;
    std::copy(common_res.begin(), common_res.end(), std::back_inserter(filtered));
```

---

Full program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ranges::take_view res = std::views::iota(1,10)
        | std::views::filter([](const int val){return val %2 == 0;})
        | std::views::transform([](const int val){return val*3;})
        | std::views::take(2);

    std::vector<int> filtered;
    std::ranges::copy(res, std::back_inserter(filtered));
    for (const auto val : filtered) {
        std::cout << "val: " << val << '\n';
    }
}
```